# Tokens in email don't work

Tags: emails, tokens

Under `admin/config/people/accounts`, in mails, there is a 'notification of comment' email, where I edited in the following text:

> Hi, [user:name]!
>
> [comment:author] commented on [comment:node:title].

I took the tokens from "Browse available tokens" below the text field.
When it sends the email to the user, the mail looks like this:

> Hi, [user:name]!
>
> [comment:author] commented on [comment:node:title].

so the tokens don't work. (In the "account activation" email, the tokens *do* work).